# Ordering Multidimensional arrays

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array, but am not sure if this is the correct way to go about it. So far, I am getting my 5 numbers in the multidimensional array and then moving them into a single dimensional array and using array sort. Does know a better way ? or have ideas on how to improve mine? Also , the code currently isn't working in the sorting area, it gives me an index out of array error.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
Module q
    Sub Main()
        Randomize()
        Dim Player,RandomNumber,NumberOfPlayers,Index As Integer
        Dim Roll as Integer = 0
        Console.Write("How many people will be playing Yahtzed?: ")
        Player = convert.toint32(Console.Readline)
        NumberOfPlayers = Player
        Dim Game(Player,5) As Integer
        Do until Player = 0
            Console.Write("User")
            Roll = 0
            Do until Roll = 5
                RandomNumber = CINT(Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1))
                Game(Player,Roll) = RandomNumber
                Roll += 1
                Console.Write(" "&RandomNumber)
            Loop 
            Player -= 1
            Console.Writeline()
        Loop 
        Player = NumberOfPlayers
        Do until Player = 0
            Dim Ordering(5) as Integer
            Roll = 0
            Do until Roll = 5
                Ordering(Index) = Game(Player,Roll)
                Roll += 1
                Index += 1
                Array.Sort(Ordering)
            Loop
        Loop
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I suspect you want an array of arrays instead of a 2-dimensional array. Or, better, a List of arrays. Is the idea to have a sorted list of dice rolls per player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way of iterating arrays is done using a For-statement

```
Const  NPlayers As Integer = 5, NRolls As Integer = 5

Dim game = New Integer(NPlayers - 1, NRolls - 1) {}
Dim randomizer As New Random()
Dim randomNumber As Integer

For p As Integer = NPlayers - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For r As Integer = 0 To NRolls - 1
        randomNumber = randomizer.[Next](10)
        game(p, r) = randomNumber
    Next 
Next
```

The array indexes always go from `0` to `arraysize-1`.

The size of your Ordering array would be `NPlayers * NRolls`

```
Dim Ordering(NPlayers * NRolls - 1) As Integer
```

Yours is too short. Therefore you get an exception.

---

Integer random numbers can be created using the `Random` class

```
Dim randomizer As New Random()
Dim randomNumber As Integer

...

randomNumber = randomizer.[Next](10)
```

This creates random numbers between 0 and 10. Create the randomizer only once and then get the next random number by calling the `Next` method.

(You must put the `Next` method between brackets, because `Next` is a keyword in VB.)

---

**UPDATE**

I assume that you want to sort the rolls per player. The easierst way to accomplish this is to use a jagged array instead.

```
Const  NPlayers As Integer = 5, NRolls As Integer = 5

Dim game = New Integer(NPlayers - 1)() {}
For p As Integer = NPlayers - 1 To 0 Step -1
    game(p) = New Integer(NRolls - 1) {}
    For r As Integer = 0 To NRolls - 1
        game(p)(r) = randomizer.[Next]()
    Next
    Array.Sort(game(p))
Next
```

But the you will have to access the rolls with `game(p)(r)` instead of `game(p,r)`.

Comment: How would I going about sorting these random numbers once they are outputted though ?

Comment: Please see my update. Such an array is called jagged array, because each row can be of a different length. You could write `game(0) = New Integer(2) {}` and `game(1) = New Integer(17) {}` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help you I bet if you sketch this out.  There is no real difference between a single dimension array and a multi dimensional array, it's purely your own thought process.  Consider a 5x3 array consisting of a grid of rolls of 5 dice.  We could organize it two ways:

As a 2 dimensional:
start of array -> roll 1 -> 1 2 3 4 5
roll 2 -> 2 4 2 1 5
roll 3 -> 2 5 4 3 2

Or as a 1 dimensional:
start of array -> 1 2 3 4 5 2 4 2 1 5 2 5 4 3 2

Either way you have to arbitrarily determine how you're dividing up your chunks of memory blocks.  In the 2 dimensional case you're pre-marking the first array index to basically say "Each second dimension will hold 5 integers."  In memory you'd figure out where you are like so:
memory_address = offset to get to your array's memory space + [1st_Dim]*sizeof(5 integers) +  [2nd_Dim]*sizeof(integer)

The one dimensional case does this instead:
memory_address = offset to get to your array's memory space + [1st_Dim]*sizeof(integer)

The two addresses will be identical as long as you're careful about knowing you're at the right index.

Draw this out on paper and run through your indexing, it'll help you understand what you're iterating through.